# Does the Alternating group of degree $n>7$ have exactly one irreducible character of degree $n-1$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

We know that the alternating group of degree $n>7$ has an irreducible character of degree $n-1$. The latter number is the smallest nontrivial one for each the alternating group has an irreducible character of that degree.

Does the Alternating group of degree $n>7$ have exactly one irreducible character of degree $n-1$?

Comment: Yes. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_symmetric_group  I expect someone can give you a reference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Old answer:** You know already that the answer is ``yes.'' For a reference, see result 2 of

> Rasala, Richard *On the minimal degrees of characters of $S_n$*. J. Algebra 45 (1977), no. 1, 132–181.

This gives the answer for $n\geq 9$. The  *Atlas of Finite Groups* then gives the result for $n=7,8,9$. (Note that the statement is also true for $n=7$, but not for $n=6$.)

I can email you copies of these sources should you need them.

**New answer:** I was unhappy with the previous answer, because one should be able to answer this using basic facts about the representation theory of the symmetric group. Here is such an answer: my reference is Fulton and Harris' *Representation theory*.

We know that irreducible reps of $S_n$ are associated to partitions $\lambda$ of $n$. Given such a partition $\lambda$, there are several formulae for the dimension of the associated irreducible rep - see (4.10), (4.11) and (4.12) of F&H. The latter is the hook length formula, which reads:

$$ \dim(V_\lambda)=\frac{d!}{\prod (\textrm{ Hook lengths})}.$$

Using this formula it is easy to work out that, for $n\geq 7$, there are only four reps of $S_n$ of degree less than $n$ - two of dim $1$ and two of dim $n-1$ (this is Exercise 4.14 of F&H). It's pretty obvious what they all are - each pair correspond to partitions that are conjugate to each other.

Now one uses Proposition 5.1 of F&H to see which of these remain as irreducibles when one restricts to the alternating group $A_n$ - the answer is that they remain irreducible so long as the associated partition is not self-conjugate. None of the partitions in question are self-conjugate so they remain irreducible; what is more representations corresponding to partitions that are conjugate yield isomorphic representations when one restricts to $A_n$ - this yields our irreducible reps for $A_n$ of dimension $1$ and $n-1$.

Now to complete the proof one needs to check that there are no self-conjugate partitions of $n$ for which the associated irreducible rep has dimension $\leq 2(n-1)$. (If there were these would split in half to yield irreducible representations of $A_n$.) This is easy.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Result 2 of Rasala's paper is only saying that $n-1$ is the second least irreducible degree character of $S_n$ (not $A_n$). It can be shown that $n-1$ can be occured as the degree of an irreducible character of $A_n$. My question is about the uniqueness of such a character of degree $n-1$ for all $n>7$ for $A_n$. I know that the character is $\chi$ (see above, my comment for Dror Speiser). I would like to know if a implicit reference for the latter.  Thanks to ban of Elsevier by some brave people, the paper can be freely downloaded from the publihser.

Comment: @Alireza, I'm just about to add a better answer.

Comment: I am grateful to you.

Answer (score 7):

As dear Derek Holt said, the answer is yes. These two references are related to this problem:

$1)$ "The Faithful Linear Representation of Least Degree of $S_n$ and $A_n$ over a Field of Characteristic 2" by $A.$ $Wagner$.

$2)$ "The Faithful Linear Representations of Least Degree of $S_n$ and $A_n$ over a Field of Odd Characteristic" by $A.$ $Wagner$.

The links for downloading these paper are:

"https://eudml.org/doc/172437"

"https://eudml.org/doc/172514"

Comment: Stefan, if there is a faithful linear representation of some degree d in characteristic 0, there also exist a faithful linear representation of the same degree in any sufficiently large characteristic.

Comment: The answer of the question could not be obtained directly from these two papers.
Could you please refer me to a reference that directly examines this question?

Comment: @Shahrooz: The author's name is actually "Ascher Wagner" (with "Ascher" as the first name).  Also, you should spell out the connection with characteristic 0 representations.

Comment: @Shahrooz. After some thought I did not arrive to the conclusion that how you can derive the uniqueness of the irreducible character of degree $n-1$ From these two papers which are about nonzero characteristic. The symmetric group of degree $n$ has two irreducible character of degree $n-1$ corresponding to the partitions $n-1,1$ and $2, 1^{n-2}$. I think one must show that these two irreducible characters give only one character for the alternating. Actually I need an explicite reference as Derek Holt mentioned above it is widely known since it is quoted in the Wikipedia.

Comment: Dear Abdollahi, it seems that you are right. When I studied these papers, I thought that it is not difficult to prove your question. But now, I am reading these papers more carefully.

Comment: Dear Jim, thanks for your good spelling comment.

Comment: @Alireza: isn't one such representation necessarily the other times the sign?

Comment: @Dror: The character $\chi$ is defined by $\chi(g)=|fix(g)|-1$ for all $g\in A_n$, where $fix(g)$ is the set of fixed points of $g$ on its natural action on $\lbrace 1,\dots,n\rbrace$. The restriction of sign times $\chi$  is the same as $\chi$ on $A_n$.

Comment: @AlirezaAbdollahi: I meant the two characters of $S_n$ you mention. Or do mean they both have the definition you just gave? (if so, I'm not sure I understand what you meant about what one must show)

Comment: @DrorSpeiser: the irreducible characters of $S_n$ of degree $n-1$ (for $n>6$) are $\chi$ and $sign \chi$, where $\chi$ is defined as above. The restriction of $\chi$ to $A_n$ is irreducible, so it remains to prove its uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

**Uniqueness.**

With respect to *the proposition 20.13* provided in the book *Representations and characters of groups* by James and Liebeck, and the answer given above by Nick Gill, the uniqueness of the "irreducible character of degree $ n−1$" is satisfied.